# Is an answer including commercial software on topic on U&L?

Tags: discussion, support

On my main site, (AU) answers including commercial software are on-topic as long as it's relevant and you're not the owner or you disclose you're the owner and you don't use the platform to SPAM.

As I just [posted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/480598/90054) an answer referring someone to commercial software (although with a money-back guarantee) just asking if that's allowed here too as some rules seem to be interpreted slightly differently by different mods on different sites.

<sub>**Note:** I personally own a copy of said software but am not Commercially affiliated with GRC in any way: I'm just a happy user.</sub>

Comment: It seems to me the relevant demarcation is free vs proprietary software. Not commercial vs noncommercial. Since even Free Software is potentially commercial. I could put up an ad to sell copies of the GNU Emacs program for USD 1000 per license, and it would be perfectly legal, though only a lunatic would  buy it. In fact, something similar used to be an important source of funding for the GNU Project/FSF, though that was before the rise of the Internet.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I'm not convinced that the relevant criteria for you are also relevant to others. The vast majority of Linux users happily use *gratis* proprietary software, most probably do without even knowing.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev When it comes to software, it's the really significant distinction, whether users recognize it or not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think there is any rule against mentioning commercial software in an answer; indeed not all Unix variants are open source. I think we'd even be fine with pointing to software you're selling, provided  the relationship is disclosed and most importantly its actually, truly an on-topic answer to the question. What we of course do not tolerate is spam, but if someone asks a question where the answer really is to go buy a given program, that's not spam. And (for if this answer is referenced in future situations) of course this is presuming everything done in good faith; e.g., it wouldn't apply to someone asking—or having a shill ask—a question just so he could promote his program; that'd be spam.

In this case, I'm somewhat confused though — isn't that a Windows program, so not really helpful to someone running a Unix/Unix-like OS? Also, does it have any hope of recovering from a disk that doesn't even report its capacity correctly?